# Showing that $P_r(x)=\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos x+r^2}\rightarrow 0$ uniformly on $[-\pi,-\delta]\cup[\delta,\pi]$ as $r\uparrow 1$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence, harmonic-functions

> Let $0<r<1$ and consider the series $$s = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty r^{|n|}e^{inx}.$$

I have shown that the series converges uniformely to $$P_r(x)=\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos x+r^2}$$ on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Now I am asked to...

> Show that for every $0<\delta<\pi$, $P_r(x)\rightarrow 0$ uniformely on the intervals $[-\pi,-\delta,]\cup[\delta,\pi]$ as $r\uparrow 1$.

Now, first off I am not entirely sure what this means: In order to talk about uniform convergence, do we not need a sequence of functions? Should I construct such a sequence to work with, e.g. $\{P_{1-\frac{1}{n}}(x)\}_n$? If so, does the problem now become: Given $\epsilon>0$, find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\ge N$ then $|P_{1-\frac{1}{n}}(x)-0|<\epsilon$ on all of $[-\pi,-\delta]\cup[\delta,\pi]$?

Comment: You may want $\forall \epsilon>0$, there is $r_\epsilon$ so that $|P_r(x) -0|<\epsilon$ for all $ r_\epsilon <r<1$.

Comment: Since the numerator tends to $0$ independently of $x$ when $r$ tends to $1$, you need to find a uniform upper bound on $\frac{1}{1-2r\cos(x)+r^2}$, which is the same a finding a uniform lower bound on $ 1-2r\cos(x)+r^2$. I can write a full answer, but maybe this helps already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One does not need a sequence of functions to discuss uniform convergence.  The concept applies to continuous variables also.  Here, there are two variables, $x$ and $r$.  If $x=0$, then note that $P(r,x=0)=\frac{1+r}{1-r}$, which is undefined for $r=1$.  If $x\ne 0$, then clearly $P(r,x \ne 0) \to 0$ as $r \to 1$.

So, when is this convergence uniform?  To prove uniform convergence on a set, given $\epsilon >0$, one needs to find a $\eta > 0$ independent on $x$, such that $|P-1|<\epsilon$ whenever $|r-1|< \eta $ for all $x$ is a set.  (Note, we used $\eta$ here so as to avoid confusion with the $\delta$ specified in the problem statement.)

Now, we can write

$$\left|\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos x +r^2}\right|=\left|\frac{1-r^2}{(1-r)^2+4r\sin^2(x/2)}\right|\le \left|\frac{(r+1)(r-1)}{4r\sin^2(x/2)}\right|=\frac{r+1}{4r}\frac{\left|(r-1)\right|}{\sin^2(x/2)}$$

Note that provided $\pi\le |x|>\delta$, then

$$1 \ge \sin^2(x/2)>\sin^2(\delta /2)$$

To complete the proof, first take $0<\eta<1/2$.  Then, certainly $(r+1)/4r < 3/4$.

Thus, given $\epsilon >0$,

$$\left| \frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos x +r^2} \right| \le \frac34  \frac{\left|r-1\right|}{\sin^2(\delta/2)}<\epsilon$$

whenever $|r-1|< \eta =\min (1/2, 4\epsilon \sin^2(\delta/2)/3 )$.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! I am curious: Is the approach outlined in my question equivalent? Could I prove uniform convergence by first constructing such a sequence?

Comment: If you want to work with sequences (which is equivalent), you need to have convergence for ANY sequence $(r_n)$ converging to $1$ from below. Proving it for just one sequence ( for instance $r_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$) is not enough.

Comment: @ThibautDumont Aha, ok. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And as demonstrated, there is no need to create a sequence of functions here.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, we have
$$s=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}r^{|n|}e^{inx}
=1+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}r^ne^{inx}+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}r^ne^{-inx}
=1+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(re^{ix}\right)^n+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(re^{-ix}\right)^n$$
$$=1+\frac{re^{ix}}{1-re^{ix}}+\frac{re^{-ix}}{1-re^{-ix}}
=1+\frac{2r\cos\left(x\right)-2r^2}{1-2r\cos\left(x\right)+r^2}
=\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos\left(x\right)+r^2}=P_r\left(x\right)$$
and the convergence is uniform for all $0<r<1$.

The second question has been discussed by John, Thibaut Dumont and Dr. MV.

Comment: Thank you, sir! But I had in fact already done this, as I stated in the problem. :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it was a question!! Anyway, it can be useful for some other users. ^^